# Where do I find scripts generated by SharePoint MCMS Migration Profiles

Tags: sharepoint, migration

I am attempting to migrate data from an *Microsoft Content Management Server (MCMS) 2002* instance into a new *Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server (MOSS) 2007* installation using the **Manage Microsoft Content Management Server Migration Profiles** tool in the **Operations** space of **MOSS Central Administration**.

When analyzing the profile, I receive 4 warnings, all of which may be safely ignored, but when I actually execute the migration profile, I get the same warnings and an additional error with a description of:

```
Line 6: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

I have seen this error numerous times when mucking about in SQL Server and recognize it as a Transact SQL error message, but can't find the actual SQL statement that is being executed so that I may determine the source of the error.

**EDIT:** After enabling verbose logging on the *MCMS 2002 Migration* category, and poring through the *Unified Logging Service (ULS)* logs, I received a more complete stack trace at the point of the error, and a couple more anomalies listed below.

**Anomalies:**
The following is an abbreviated listing from the ULS logs around the time of the pre-migration analysis.

```
01 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  Start ConnectionCheck
02 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  End ConnectionCheck
03 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  Start DatabaseCheck
04 MCMS 2002 Migration   High     Extra table SiteDeployLock will not be migrated
05 MCMS 2002 Migration   High     Analysis: Extra index PK__SiteDeployLock__05D8E0BE
06 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  End DatabaseCheck
07 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: RootCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
08 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: RightsGroupNameCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
09 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: InvalidNameCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
10 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: LeafNameCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
11 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: LeafLengthCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
12 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: TemplateNameCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
13 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: TemplateCollisionCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
14 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: PlaceholderCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
15 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: CheckedOutItemsCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
16 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: SubmittedItemsCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
17 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: DeletedItemsCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
18 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: UserCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
19 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: FileSizeCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
20 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   Pre-migration analysis: HostHeaderMapCheckTask is skipped because database check is blocked.
21 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  Start Server check
22 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  End Server check
23 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  Start Server emptyness check
24 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  End Server emptyness check
25 MCMS 2002 Migration   Medium   PreMigrationAnalyzer: Dry run starts
26 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  CleanLockProcedure: start.
27 MCMS 2002 Migration   High     CleanLockProcedure: connection system lock is null
28 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  Finished all tasks
29 MCMS 2002 Migration   High     PreMigrationAnalyzer ends with True
30 MCMS 2002 Migration   Verbose  Migration profile status is changed to AnalysisPassed
```

Specifically, the two *High* level alerts on lines 4 and 5 are reflected in the migration report as warnings when running Pre-migration Analysis or running the migration profile.  In addition, two other warnings appear in the migration report indicating two tables containing data (`LayoutProperty` and `NodeLayout`) that should be empty.  According to the documentation, warnings are not sufficient cause to stop migration from occurring.  Other anomalies are on lines 7-20 indicating a series of tests that are `skipped because database check is blocked.`  The ULS doesn't give any additional warnings to indicate that the database check was blocked or exited in exceptional circumstances.

After switching the profile from *pre-migration analysis* to *exporting*, there is one medium level warning that `LastChangeTime is not set or incorrect. (null)`.  As with all the skipped test names and SQL table names from the warnings, the major search engines are unable (with the exception of `LayoutProperty`) to find any reference to these objects or tests.

Finally, the section of the log indicating the actual live migration attempt is appended below:

```
01 MCMS 2002 Migration  Medium   LastChangeTime is not set or incorrect. (null)
02 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  Set export lock
03 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  CleanLockProcedure: start.
04 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  CleanLockProcedure: end.
05 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  Prepare for export
06 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  Open connection...
07 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  Create temporary stored procedures
08 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  Create temporary tables...
09 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  Initialize temporary tables...
10 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  InitializeTemporaryTables: start
11 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  Initialize export table...
12 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  InitializeExportTable: start
13 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  CleanLockProcedure: start.
14 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  CleanLockProcedure: end.
15 MCMS 2002 Migration  High     Migration throws exception: Line 6: Incorrect syntax near ';'.. Stacktrace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration...
16 MCMS 2002 Migration  High     ....MigrationBatchCommand.ExecuteImmediate(String command)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationBatchCommand.ExecuteWaitingCommands()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDBSerializer.SerializeSelectedExportObject(StringCollection objectAttribs)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDataAccess.InitializeExportTable(ScopeType scopeType)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDataAccess.InitializeTemporaryTables(DateTime lastChangeTime)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDataAccess.InitializeDatabase(DateTime lastChangeTime, Boolean isAnalysis, SqlConnection connection)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Admin...
17 MCMS 2002 Migration  High     ...stration.MigrationDataAccess.InitializeDatabase(DateTime lastChangeTime, Boolean isAnalysis)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentMigration.Export(MigrationDataAccess dataAccess)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentMigration.MigrateInternal().
18 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  MigrationProfile: GetInstance. Start.
19 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  MigrationProfile: GetInstance. End.
20 MCMS 2002 Migration  Verbose  Migration profile status is changed to Failed
```

The stack trace of the failed parsing of the SQL command appear on lines 15-17.  A cleaner version of the stack trace is appended below.

**Full Stack Trace:**

```
Migration throws exception: Line 6: Incorrect syntax near ';'..
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
     Boolean breakConnection)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(
     TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
     SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet
     bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName,
     Boolean async)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result,
     String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationBatchCommand
     .ExecuteImmediate(String command)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationBatchCommand
     .ExecuteWaitingCommands()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDBSerializer
     .SerializeSelectedExportObject(StringCollection objectAttribs)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDataAccess
     .InitializeExportTable(ScopeType scopeType)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDataAccess
     .InitializeTemporaryTables(DateTime lastChangeTime)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDataAccess
     .InitializeDatabase(DateTime lastChangeTime, Boolean isAnalysis,
     SqlConnection connection)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Administration.MigrationDataAccess
     .InitializeDatabase(DateTime lastChangeTime, Boolean isAnalysis)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentMigration.Export
     (MigrationDataAccess dataAccess)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentMigration
     .MigrateInternal().
```

None of this log information indicates the SQL command that is failing a parser check.  I've checked the SQL servers hosting the source and destination databases for a trace of the query, but neither seems to have triggered the parse failure condition.  That appears to have happened on the SharePoint server.

Are there any other locations I should investigate that might tell me where to find the source of the error?

Answer (score 1):

ULS logs will have the data you are looking for.  Turn your SharePoint logging to Verbose and then start digging.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the Universal Logging Service.  I found a decent tool for parsing and filtering these logs (Stefan Gordon's SharePoint ULS Viewer).  I am now able to assert more confidently that my original assessment is correct, but have no deeper information about the specific failing query.